# C# - ODP.NET and ora-01475 must reparse cursor to change bind variable datatype

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I'm getting `ora-01475` whenever I try to insert a null value in a column (of type `DateTime`) after some records have already been inserted that have real date values.

I'm using the `OracleParameter` constructor that takes the name and the value as an object (I assume the data type is then implied from the datatype of the object), but since sometimes the value of my parameter is null, it's being set as a `String`, therefore throwing this error.

I don't want to use the constructor that takes the datatype explicitly because I use reflection heavily to build the `OracleCommand` object and its parameters.

How can I reparse the cursor (as the error suggests) if I find this situation?
Has anyone else run into this and has a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use nullable types?

```
            DateTime? myDate;
            //Code to set myDate value...
            string sql = "[your SQL]"
            using (OracleCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                OracleParameter param = new OracleParameter(":Name",myDate);
                command.Paerameters.add(param);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly the reason why I'm getting the problem, because in the first query I pass a null and then later on I pass a real date...I've solved it by explicitly specifying the Parameter DBType to Date, even if it's null. Thanks!